# Windows 8 download on Mac

Tags: windows, macos

I am planning to install Windows 8 on a second computer I'm building. I have a product key and have found Microsoft's downloader. The problem is that the downloader is an EXE (Windows program) and I only have 1 operational Mac now. How can I download a legitimate Windows ISO onto my Mac?

Comment: Microsoft provides free windows virtual machines. All you need is something like Virtual Box, load it up, and use the supplied Setup.exe to download the .iso Be sure you select to download the file instead of the installation option. VMWare likely has a free virtual machine software on OS X also.  Just convert the .vhd to a support file type.

Comment: @Ramhound where can I get these VMs?

Comment: You can find them on the Microsoft website.

Comment: @Fanj Here's the link: http://modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads